# What is meaning of backslash aftera a folder directory?

Tags: directory, path, environment-variables, explorer

What is the difference between "C:\Android\sdk" and "C:\Android\sdk\" when adding path in environment variables or any other place?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. A trailing backslash (or slash in the case of UNIX) is ignored by the operating system. There are only two uses that I know of. First, dealing with broken programs that incorrectly assume a trailing slash/backslash is present when concatenating the value to another relative path. Second, a very small number of commands (e.g., `scp`) might assign special meaning to a trailing path delimiter.